# Partially overwrite in a file through script

Tags: command-line, scripts

I see

`<command> >> <filepath>` appends the command line to the file

and

`<command> > <filepath>` replaces the entire contents of the file with the command given passed.

How to pass the command to the file so that only the *last line* of the file is overwritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not built in to the shell in the same way simple overwrite and append are. You have to do it in two steps, first remove the last line, then append:

```
X=$(head -n -1 filepath)
echo "$X" > filepath
command >> filepath
```

Or you can overwrite with the new contents all at once:

```
X=$(head -n -1 test)
(echo "$X"; command) > test
```

Note that in both cases, we capture the old lines that we want to keep in a variable first as a separate command. This is because as soon as a command with a ">" directive begins executing, the shell will clear the file, and any attempt to read those lines will be too late.

Comment: Oh ok! Didn't know about capturing part of the string :-) The net result is just what I wanted. Thanks!